# Touch ID Crash issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

Actually I am facing issue in the TouchID implementation. I want to implement a passcode functionality like Apple. My is problem is that I don't want to show any alert to the user like Apple.

```
NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = <#String explaining why app needs authentication#>;
if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
[myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
```

Here if I don't send `myLocalizedReasonString` the app will crash.

Answer (score 3):

You have to show an alert and provide a reason string. It is part of Apple's privacy and security requirements for iOS. You need to inform the user why you are requesting a Touch ID authentication